# Find a random combination of arrays with a total length of 10, and splittable into two groups of 5

Tags: javascript, combinations

Let's say I have an array with arrays, such as:

```
const array = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e'],
    ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    ['k'],
    ['l'],
    ['m'],
    ['n', 'o', 'p'],
    ['q', 'r', 's'],
    ['t', 'u', 'v'],
    ['x']
];
```

I want to select any combination at random that respects the following rules:

- The total length of all the selected combinations must always be 10. A possible result could be the first 3 items of the `array`
- The selected combinations must be able to be split into two groups of 5. Again, the first 3 items would respect that condition: the `length` of `['a', 'b, 'c']` + the `length` of `['d', 'e']` equals `5`, and at the same time, the length of  `['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']`equals `5`. That's two groups of `5`. The last 4 elements of the `array`, on the other hand, wouldn't be able to fulfill this condition, even though they respect the first one (total length = 10).

It might help to know the purpose of this: I have a little multiplayer game. Games need 2 teams of 5 players. And players can enter the game with a friend to play on the same team (or even 5 friends, instantly filling an entire team).

The idea: players would press 'Start'. Then my function would push them into an array like the one above. Each time a push happened, the player/team function (which I'm asking for your help) would run. If a match were found, the game would start.

I have a feeling that this would be best accomplished with some kind of recursive function, but my head is having trouble figuring it out.

---

After a long couple of hours here's the solution I came up with. Passed all my tests.

```
//const { shuffle, flatten } = require('lodash');

const pool = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e'],
    ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    ['k'],
    ['l'],
    ['m'],
    ['n', 'o', 'p'],
    ['q', 'r', 's'],
    ['t', 'u', 'v'],
    ['x']
];

function getMaxPickSize ( draw ) {
    let x = 5;
    let y = 5;

    draw.forEach( pick => {

        if ( x - pick.length >= 0 ) {
            x -= pick.length;

        } else if ( y - pick.length >= 0 ) {
            y -= pick.length;
        }

    });

    return Math.max(x,y);
}


function doDraw( pool ) {
    //no need to move further if there arent even 10 players
    if ( _.flatten(pool).length < 10 ) {
        return false;
    }

    // keep register of all draws and pools, and items. if we 
    // figure out an attempt doesnt work, we can go back anytime
    // and skip picks that dont work
    let prevs = [
        // array of objects that will look like this.
        // {   
        //     pool: [],
        //     draw: [],
        //     skip: []
        // }
        // ...
    ];

    //let's try. First step, shuffle the pool;
    pool = _.shuffle(pool);

    function doIt( curr_pool, curr_draw = [], skip_items_w_length ) {

        let new_pool = [...curr_pool];
        let new_draw = [...curr_draw];
        let pick;

        if ( skip_items_w_length == undefined ) {
            //in first loop it starts here
            //if we happen to have luck and fill the draw in
            //one go, the else statement below will never execute
            pick = new_pool.shift();

        } else {

            let to_skip = prevs[prevs.length - 1].skip;
            to_skip.push(skip_items_w_length);

            pick = _.find(new_pool, item => !to_skip.includes(item.length) );

            if ( pick ) {
                new_pool.splice(new_pool.indexOf(pick), 1);

            } else {
                if ( !prevs.length ) {
                    return false;
                }

                let prev = prevs.pop();
                let prev_pool = prev.pool;
                let prev_draw = prev.draw;
                let last_item_in_prev_draw = prev_draw.pop();

                return doIt(prev_pool, prev_draw, last_item_in_prev_draw.length );
            } 
        }

        new_draw = [...curr_draw, pick];

        //if draw is complete, return it
        if ( _.flatten(new_draw).length === 10 ) {
            return new_draw;
        }


        //else draw process continues
        //find items in pool that can still fit into draw
        const max_pick_size = getMaxPickSize(new_draw);
        new_pool = new_pool.filter(item => item.length <= max_pick_size);

        //if items dont contain enough players to fill remaining spots,
        //repeat this exact step, ignoring items without pick's length
        //as none of the remaining picks can follow. if we discover in
        // later repeats that no pick allows other picks to follow
        // we'll go back 1 step, using previous pool and draw, and
        // ignoring all picks with the associated picks length
        if ( _.flatten(new_pool).length < 10 - _.flatten(new_draw).length ) {
            return doIt(curr_pool, curr_draw, pick.length);
        }


        prevs.push({
            pool: curr_pool,
            draw: curr_draw,
            skip: []
        });

        return doIt(new_pool, new_draw);
    }


    return doIt(pool);

}

const draw = doDraw( pool );
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I would not have posted this question hadn't I tried anything before...

Comment: Yes, but we don't know that. It looks like you're asking us to solve the problem for you without any attempt by you to solve it yourself. You should post code you've attempted as a [mcve]. This article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you.

Comment: @banzomaikaka It likely does, though your question sounds like "hey, I need to do that, do that for me, please". Showing what you've tried to accomplish would be a great benefit to your question and won't cost you much effort, since you actually tried to do something. Don't get me wrong, this is the kind of question I would answer in any case, though showing **your effort** is always enjoyable from whoever wants to help you.

Comment: @banzomaikaka (for the record I haven't downvoted you) We don't know if you have tried something. We are not ruthless, just expected your attempt (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), or at least telling us what part you are having trouble with. Right now, it looks like you are looking for a coding service, which StackOverflow (as you should know with 12k+ rep) is not. Your question does not look trivial, I agree. But that also means people will spend a lot of their time to solve it. Help them before they help you.

Comment: I guess its easier to find groups of five (five, one + four, two + three)

Answer (score 2):

Shuffle the array, then take out unique groups till you reach five:

```js
const array = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e'],
    ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    ['k'],
    ['l'],
    ['m'],
    ['n', 'o', 'p'],
    ['q', 'r', 's'],
    ['t', 'u', 'v'],
    ['x']
];


function shuffle(arr) { /* Shuffling algorithm here */ }

shuffle(array);

// Extracts arrays with exactly "count" elements, excluding all elements in "exclude" and starting at "start" in the array
// If no combination was found, return undefined
function takeOut(array, count, start = 0, exclude = []) {
  // Base case: Count wasn't reached exactly, abort here
  if(count < 0) return;
  // Base case: Combination was found, go up
  if(count === 0) return [];

  // Go over the array to find a matching combination
  for(let i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
    const current = array[i];
    // Skip elements that should be excluded
    if(exclude.includes(current)) continue;
    
    // Recursive call: Find more elements so that a group of "count" gets reached
    const rest = takeOut(array, count - current.length, i + 1, exclude);
    if(!rest) continue; // If this element can't be matched up, go on
    return [current, ...rest];
  }
}

// Our two teams:
const first = takeOut(array, 5);
const second = takeOut(array, 5, 0, first); // all from the first team can't be in the second one

console.log(first, second);

if(first && second)
   console.log("The game can start");
```

Comment: Hey Jonas. Thanks for the answer. Let me understand how it works before anything else!

Comment: What if there are multiple ways to create the first team and not all of them will result into possibility to create the second team? For example `[2, 2, 1, 3, 3]` (number is the length of a team). First will be `[2, 2, 1]` and there is no way for second team to be created despite the fact that both can be created like this: `[[2, 3], [2, 3]]`?

Comment: I'm afk now, I'll get back to this later

Comment: I'll add to my question what I've got, even though it doesn't work.

Comment: Is randomness a requirement that has to be fullfilled in every case? Otherwise we (me and a coworker of mine) came up with a failsafe way, but that prioritizes some combinations

Comment: Thanks for both yours and your coworker's efforts. Let me think about how that would affect the experience. I'll comment once I have an answer. Thank you, Jonas!

Comment: Hey Jonas. I need that randomness factor. I've updated my code above, I think I'm getting closer. Would you like to have a look? I know there's a logic problem above. But I0m updating the code as I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the solution that may not be exactly what you wanted. Anyway I think that it may help you. It finds all possible compositions and if you need only one you can choose it randomly. I also used slightly different data model: object where keys represent team sizes and values are arrays of arrays of teams with according sizes.

```js
const UNITS_NUMBER = 2

// object format: { [number]: how-many-times-this-number-should-be-used }
const COMPOSE_VARIATIONS = [{1: 5}, {1: 3, 2: 1}, {1: 2, 3: 1}, {1: 1, 4: 1}, {1: 1, 2: 2}, {2: 1, 3: 1}, {5: 1}]

const parts = {
  1: [['k'], ['l'], ['m'], ['x']],
  2: [['d', 'e']],
  3: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['n', 'o', 'p'], ['q', 'r', 's'], ['t', 'u', 'v']],
  4: [],
  5: [['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']],
}

function getAllCompositions(allParts, unitsNumber, composeVariations) {
  const result = []
  const usedPartsStack = []
  let units = [] 
  let currentIndex = 0
  let unitsComposed = 0
  while (currentIndex < composeVariations.length) {
    const variation = composeVariations[currentIndex]
    if (canCreateUnit(allParts, variation)) {
      const unit = getPartsForUnit(allParts, variation)
      units.push(flatten(unit))
      if (unitsComposed + 1 < unitsNumber) {
        usedPartsStack.push({ index: currentIndex, partsUsedForUnit: unit })
        allParts = removeUsedParts(allParts, variation)
        unitsComposed++
      } else {
        result.push([...units])
        units.pop()
        currentIndex++
      }
    } else {
      currentIndex++
    }
    while (currentIndex === composeVariations.length && usedPartsStack.length) {
      const { index, partsUsedForUnit } = usedPartsStack.pop()
      currentIndex = index + 1
      allParts = restoreUsedParts(allParts, partsUsedForUnit)
      unitsComposed--
      units.pop()
    }
  }
  return result
}

// checks if passed variation can be used to create unit from parts from allParts object
// unit is a group of parts that forms an array with total length of 5)
function canCreateUnit(allParts, variation) {
  return Object.entries(variation).every(([length, count]) => allParts[length].length >= count)
}

// get real parts from allParts object according to variation passed
function getPartsForUnit(allParts, variation) {
  const result = []
  Object.entries(variation).forEach(([length, count]) => {
    result.push(allParts[length].slice(0, count))
  })
  return result
}

// removes parts that were used for unit creation
function removeUsedParts(allParts, variation) {
  const result = { ...allParts }
  Object.entries(variation).forEach(([length, count]) => {
    result[length] = result[length].slice(count)
  })
  return result
}

// add parts to allParts object
function restoreUsedParts(allParts, parts) {
  const result = { ...allParts }
  parts.forEach((item) => {
    result[item[0].length] = [...item, ...result[item[0].length]]
  })
  return result
}

// removes one level of nesting in array
function flatten(partsForUnit) {
  const result = []
  partsForUnit.forEach(item => {
    result.push(...item)
  })
  return result
}

function print(compositions) {
  compositions.forEach(composition => {
    composition.forEach(unit => {
      console.log(unit)
    })
    console.log('=======================================')
  })
}

print(getAllCompositions(parts, UNITS_NUMBER, COMPOSE_VARIATIONS))
```

Comment: Hey savchenkoto! Thanks a lot for your help! The compose_variations is pretty smart. Much smarter than what I'm doing. Let me test it!  I've also been working on mine too. I think it's almost complete. I'll then add it to my question above for you to see.